# Why can't `auto&` bind to a volatile rvalue expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, volatile, rvalue-reference

Consider the below code:

```
int main()
{
  int i{};
  auto& c = static_cast<const int&&>(i);    // (1)
  auto& v = static_cast<volatile int&&>(i); // (2)
}
```

While `(1)` compiles successfully, `(2)` is not accepted:

> error: volatile lvalue reference to type 'volatile int' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'volatile int'

Why can't `auto` become a `volatile int`?

Why can `auto&` become a `const int` and bind to `const int&&`? Is it because `auto&` actually binds to a temporary object that is created on the right hand side of assignment? But then, why `auto& p = 1;` doesn't work?

Answer (score 7):

This is not about `auto`, but about binding temporaries to a non-const reference.

In the first case you get a `const int&`, which is ok. I the second case, a `volatile int&` will not bind to the temporary.

Comment: Then why `auto& p = 1;` doesn't work? If it were that case, it should also compile, shouldn't it? Please note that I have an rvalue expression on the right and a non-const lvalue reference on the left

Comment: For `auto& p = 1` the deduction for `auto` is just `int`, not `const int`. With the cast, you get `const int&& &` which becomes `const int&` after folding the references.

Comment: How come it applies reference collapsing for something that is not a forwarding reference?

Comment: @Marc - That's the way references work. You cannot have an `int&&&`, so it turn into an `int&`.

Comment: There's no reference collapsing here. `auto` is deduced to be `const int` or `volatile int` directly in OP's example.