# Why returning a "modifiable" ranges view from a function causes a compile error but the same code outside the function doesn't

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

Consider this simplified example:

```cpp
using MyVar = std::variant<int, float>;
using Container = std::vector<MyVar>;

static Container myContainer;

template <typename T> auto &JustOneType()
{
    return myContainer |
           std::ranges::views::filter([](auto &var) { return std::holds_alternative<T>(var); }) |
           std::ranges::views::transform([](auto &var) -> auto & { return std::get<T>(var); });
}

void MyFun()
{

    auto x = // This is fine
        myContainer |
        std::ranges::views::filter([](auto &var) { return std::holds_alternative<int>(var); }) |
        std::ranges::views::transform([](auto &var) -> auto & { return std::get<int>(var); });

    auto y = JustOneType<int>(); // This causes a compile error
}
```

Why does the line `auto y` cause the following error?

> error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type.... to an rvalue
> of type...

But on the other hand, the line `auto x` is completely fine.

Comment: Does your question have *anything* to do with ranges?  This is just a question of why `auto& JustOneType() { return prvalue; }` doesn't work. The reason is also simple, because, you cannot bind prvalue, which is the return type of the pipe operator, to a non-const lvalue reference.

Comment: Why is `JustOneType` returning a reference?

Comment: [Why can't `auto&` bind to a volatile rvalue expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066346/why-cant-auto-bind-to-a-volatile-rvalue-expression) and [Why does this code give the error "cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘char*&’ to an rvalue of type ‘char*’"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63186574/why-does-this-code-give-the-error-cannot-bind-non-const-lvalue-reference-of-typ)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return a reference to a [prvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue).

Consider these two functions

```
auto& foo() {
    int i = 1;
    return i;  // will dangle
}
auto& bar() {
    return 1;  // does not compile
}
```

While `foo()` will compile and return a reference to an `int`, the reference will dangle, as it is a reference to the temporary  `i`. `bar()` on the other hand will not compile, because how could you take a reference to `1` (a prvalue)? You probably want `auto func()` instead of `auto& func()`.